# How to check 5222 port is open in cpanel hosting

Tags: hosting, port

I have a linux reseller account and i manage through WHM
I have created a cpanel account for my client.
He wanted the port 5222 to be open.
I am not aware of it. How to check the status, and whether it is open or not?
How to turn it on /off?

Comment: Port 5222 is for the XMPP (aka. jabber) chat protocol.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol  This would need to be opened for running an XMPP server or client application, depending on the directionality of the connection.

Answer (score 3):

```
telnet <hostname> 5222
```

Comment: Where to type this command?
I am sorry, this may seem kiddish. I am not that familiar. Please guide me

Comment: if you're on Windows, start > run `cmd` ENTER.  then `telnet <hostname> 5222`.

Answer (score 1):

With HostGator at least, clientdomain.com/cpanel redirects to clientdomain.com:2082.  I'm not aware if you can change that, but the best place to ask would be your hosting company's support.  Like solefald said, you can use the `telnet` command to test whether TCP ports are open.

Answer (score 1):

cpanel typically doesn't manage firewall.  Talk to your hosting providor or whomever manages your server.  They will have to open the port for you on the firewall.